# MySQL for each video count how many cuepoints have value greater than 50

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have a table part of which looks like 
[image: this.]

For each VideoName I want to count how many values in the Cuepoint column have value greater than 50.

Example output of the query:

```
{"VideoName":"TUTORIAL 1","Over50":"21"},
{"VideoName":"TUTORIAL 2","Over50":"23"}...
```

I also want to ask whether it is possible to create a query which outputs for each VideName how many times each Aspect was used?

Example output of the query:

```
{"VideoName":"TUTORIAL 1","Delivery":"2","Speech":"4","Visual aids":8"}...
```

And finally (hope I am not getting annoying) is it possible to create a query which determens in what order useres in the UserId column watched the different videos using the `CommentDate`?

Comment: Yes, these are all possible.

Comment: Use `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY` to count rows in groups.

Comment: Can you help me to create the queries, because I am very new to MySQL and have very little time left to do them?

Comment: Any SQL tutorial should explain how to do this. If you're taking a class, it should be in the textbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st one:

```
SELECT VideoName,COUNT(CuePoint) AS TotalCuePointsgreaterthan50
  FROM Yourtable
WHERE CuePoint >= 50
GROUP BY VideoName;
```

2nd one :

```
SELECT VideoName,
       Aspect,
       COUNT(*) AS Count_per_aspect
  FROM Yourtable
GROUP BY VideoName,Aspect;
```

Comment: First query should be `WHERE CuePoint >= 50`

Comment: And it should be `COUNT(*)` not `SUM(CuePoint)`

Comment: Added those changes.. Thanks Barmar!!

Answer (score 0):

1. For each VideoName I want to count how many values in the Cuepoint column have value greater than 50.

   ```
   Select VideoName, SUM(IF(Cuepoint > 50, 1, 0)) Over50 FROM table GROUP BY VideoName;
   ```
2. I also want to ask whether it is possible to create a query which outputs for each VideName how many times each Aspect was used?

   ```
   SELECT VideoName, count(*) aspectCount from table GROUP BY VideoName, Aspect;
   ```